# How to handle a failed port upgrade using MacPorts

Tags: macos, cmake, macports

I was doing a routine upgrade of my macports, on a Mavericks 10.9.5 OS X, and using the command "port upgrade outdated", which I do once every few weeks.  For the first time, I had a port, cmake, that failed to build.  I'm wondering what I should try to do next.  I'm not sure I should be reporting it as a bug with macports.org, so I'm wondering if there is some way to refresh/reset/clean a port and try again.  I expect is needed to build other ports, so I am a little hesitant to just remove it and try again, but I thought I would check here to see if anyone has some advice about it.  I'm including the bottom portion of the log file for the failed cmake build here:

```
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 && /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source/CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 && /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source/CMakeFiles/ccmake.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Source/CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/build.make Source/CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/build
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 && /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source/CMakeFiles/CPackLib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 && /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64 /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64/Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `bin/cmake'.  Stop.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[1]: *** [Source/CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/all] Error 2
:info:build make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Source/CMakeFiles/ccmake.dir/build.make Source/CMakeFiles/ccmake.dir/build
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `bin/ccmake'.  Stop.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[1]: *** [Source/CMakeFiles/ccmake.dir/all] Error 2
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Source/CMakeFiles/CPackLib.dir/build.make Source/CMakeFiles/CPackLib.dir/build
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[2]: Nothing to be done for `Source/CMakeFiles/CPackLib.dir/build'.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build [ 71%] Built target CPackLib
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/build.make Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/build
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make[2]: Nothing to be done for `Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/build'.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build [ 87%] Built target CTestLib
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/work/cmake-3.3.2-x86_64" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all VERBOSE=ON 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port cmake returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: NONE
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"proc-org.macports.build-build-0 org.macports.build"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for cmake: org.macports.install org.macports.build org.macports.destroot
:notice:build Please see the log file for port cmake for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/main.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that you seem to have uninstalled (or deactivated) the zlib port:

```
:info:build make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib', needed by `bin/cmake'.  Stop.
```

but cmake depends on zlib:

```
$ port deps cmake
Full Name: cmake @3.3.1_0
Library Dependencies: curl, expat, zlib, bzip2, libarchive
```

So I suspect if you do this, it should pick up the dependency and try again:

```
sudo port -v clean cmake
sudo port -v -s install cmake
```

Comment: This answer partially solved the problem.  However, after running the commands suggested, the install of cmake still failed.  The problem is that, even though zlib is installed, it still did not install /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib.  The following link gives the information for forcing zlib to install this library, after which the upgrade of cmake worked just fine: (https://trac.macports.org/ticket/23057)